# Google reCaptcha image select not responsive

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I have implemented Google reCaptcha and is working fine. But, I have got a problem with the image select that appears after multiple requests from the same IP.

The google reCaptcha image select box is not responsive. It is not positioned relatively and also is not resized or moved when the page is resized. When the page is resized even scroll bars appear since the image select box is resized accordingly.

Is there any possibility to make is responsive?